# How to check whether local branch is sync'ed with remote one?

Tags: git, libgit2

I'm trying to rewrite existent and very old `git` GUI frontend - just for fun.
The idea is to replace `git` external process calls to `libgit2` library methods.
However, looks like it still lacks some of basic git features.

My current pain is `git status`:

```
eraxillanmac:test eraxillan$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
...
```

I can got current branch name and changed files using `libgit2`: [official example](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/examples/status.c)

But how i can get this string?

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

I suspect i need to use `remote`/`fetch` groups of `libgit2` API, but still don't understand how.

Thanks!

Comment: "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'." means that the branch you're currently on, a.k.a `HEAD`, points to the same OID that the upstream branch is at. *edit* And there's https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/graph/git_graph_ahead_behind, once you have got the OIDs.

Comment: @tiennou No, `git status` also tracks whether local branch is sync with remote counterpart. Test: exec `git commit` and check `git status` - it changes. About function - i'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of what `git status` does internally is: resolve HEAD, look for its (possible) upstream, check the graph to see who's ahead, by how much, and show "ahead/behind/up to date", as well as mergeability (so you get `and can be fast-forwarded/etc.`).